# Wordpress Close theme menu after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using [this](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/ichiban-a-theme-for-photographers/full_screen_preview/10839660) Wordpress theme, called ichiban.
I have made some custom menu items that links directly to sections on the same page. For these cases I would like the whole menu to un-toggle when the < li > item is clicked. This is the code I have been working on;

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $('#menu-main li a').on("click", function(){
        $('.site-overlay-wrapper').hide();
    });

});
```

For now, this code only hides the open menu, the menu button does not reset, and it is not possible to re-ope the menu. Please help me getting this code correct.

**SOLUTION**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $('#menu-main li a').on("click", function(){
        $("body").removeClass("overlay-open");
    });

});
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using jQuery [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

Change this line:

```
$('.site-overlay-wrapper').hide();
```

To:

```
$('.site-overlay-wrapper').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    var t = true;
    $('#menu-main li a').on("click", function(){
        if(t===true){
            $('.site-overlay-wrapper').hide();
            t=false;
        }
        else{
            $('.site-overlay-wrapper').show();
            t=true;
        }
    });

});
```

Here is working example:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        var t = true;
        $('#button').on("click", function(){
            if(t===true){
                $('.show').hide();
              $(this).text("SHOW");
                t=false;
            }
            else{
                $('.show').show();
              $(this).text("HIDE");
                t=true;
            }
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">CLICK</button>
<div class="show">HAPPY NEW YEAR!!!</div>
```

You also can have a problem with `$('#menu-main li a')`. That a tag is wrong. You need to point click statement to button class directly because you hide your menu on any `a` tag inside any `li`.

Comment: Thank you for trying! But this code only hide the menu, but does not reset the menu button and it's still not possible the re-open the menu. I think maybe I am using the wrong class to hide.

Comment: `$('#menu-main li a')` is your problem I think. That `a` tag is wrong. You need to point click statemant to button class directly because you hide your menu on any `a` tag inside any `li`